# Booting/Filesystem corruption 18.04

Tags: boot, kernel

I have hugely messed up my computer I think. [here is a reddit thread with more info](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/a3h0x0/1804_login_screen_never_lets_me_in/ebb8j8x/?context=8&depth=9)

Hard to explain all of it, but the thread has all of the info and pastebin stuff.

There is "partition 1" which has all of my tweaks and has been my os for the last month, love it. But, ran into many problems with booting. I have created a new partition out of frustration and wanting a working computer but did some fixes the redditor suggested (updated kernel and bios) and now my new (was working fine) partition is not recognizing. Would wiping my ssd work? I don't care about my stuff anymore, I just want a working pc. If I wipe my ssd won't my bios and mobo stuff still be corrupted? Should I just buy a new mobo and start again? I'm quite a noob and didn't forsee this many problems.

Comment: The stuff on you MOBO and BIOS should not be affected by using the USB to reformat and reinstall on your SSD.

Comment: But I think those are the places where my problems lie. If my bios is all messed up won't it continue to be if I completely wipe and reinstall 18.04

Comment: The motherboard is pretty much hardware - if you've been plugging in new/odd stuff, there is little we can do to assist you.  The BIOS is burn't into a chip on the motherboard - this is something that you need to take specific steps to change, and most likely you did not change these with your OS tweaks

Comment: How did you exactly "updated kernel and bios"?